# Windows 10 elevates some of my apps that Windows 7 didn't

Tags: command-line, windows-10

After upgrading to Windows 10, my .NET app now requests UAC permission from the user to allow it to make changes, even though no such changes occur.  This unfortunately elevates the app in order to run, but this hides the (subst'd) drives that it requires.  How can I suppress the elevation, or, how can I execute it such that it can see all my normal-access drives.  Recreating those subst'd drives in admin mode is not an option, nor does "net use" have different results.  Also, tried setting EnableLinkedConnections DWORD value in the registry to no avail

Comment: How is it a DOS question? Any more details about your apps or why that could be?

Comment: I can execute the app from a DOS Command Console or the Run menu option and it works without elevation, but starting the app by its shortcut elevates (the shortcut does NOT have 'Run as Administrator' set).  I tried to create a bat file that starts the app but this also elevates.  Tried the DOS start command in the bat file but still elevates.  It seems there's no shortcut solution to starting the app without elevation.  I'm hopeful there's a magic DOS solution that works when initiated by a shortcut.  The app is a .NET app that opens and reads a file from the drives I've subst'd.